# Paperclip and Amazon S3 how to do paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

How do I create paths with paperclip when using Amazon S3?

My directory on my bucket is:

```
/image/:id/:filename
```

My model:

```
  has_attached_file :image,
    :storage => :s3,
    :bucket => 'mybucket',
    :s3_credentials => {
      :access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET']
    }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
  has_attached_file :image,
    :storage => :s3,
    :bucket => 'mybucket',
    :path => "/image/:id/:filename",
    :s3_credentials => {
      :access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET']
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

I wrote a post about it a few months back.
I also wrote about how you can add properties from the class, for example not using an id (I don't like it) and using a token instead.

[Read the post here...](http://www.kensodev.com/2010/12/17/use-token-instead-of-id-in-paperclips-path/)

The basics:

to get a path with an id

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
  :styles =>
  {
    :tiny => "48x48>",
    :preview => "175x175>",
    :large => "300x300>",
    :huge => "500x500>"
  },
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
  :path => ":class/:attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
  :bucket => 'lopsum',
  :default_url => "/images/photo01.jpg"
```

and, if you want to change it to something else...

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
  :styles =>
  {
    :tiny => "48x48>",
    :preview => "175x175>",
    :large => "300x300>",
    :huge => "500x500>"
  },
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
  :path => ":class/:attachment/:token/:style.:extension",
  :bucket => 'lopsum',
  :default_url => "/images/photo01.jpg"
```

and in an initializer

```
Paperclip.interpolates :token do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.token
end
```