# Associate object to pre-existing file on S3, using Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip, fog

I have a file already on S3 that I'd like to associate to a pre-existing instance of the Asset model.

Here's the model:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible(:attachment_content_type, :attachment_file_name,
                 :attachment_file_size, :attachment_updated_at, :attachment)

  has_attached_file :attachment, {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
      access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    },
    convert_options: { all: '-auto-orient' },
    url: ':s3_alias_url',
    s3_host_alias: ENV['S3_HOST_ALIAS'],
    path: ":class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename",
    bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    s3_protocol: 'https'
  }
end
```

Let's say the path is `assets/attachments/000/111/file.png`, and the `Asset` instance I want to associate with the file is `asset`. Referring at the [source](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb), I've tried:

```
options = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
      access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    },
    convert_options: { all: '-auto-orient' },
    url: ':s3_alias_url',
    s3_host_alias: ENV['S3_HOST_ALIAS'],
    path: "assets/attachments/000/111/file.png",
    bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    s3_protocol: 'https'
  }
# The above is identical to the options given in the model, except for the path

Paperclip::Attachment.new("file.png", asset, options).save
```

As far as I can tell, this did not affect `asset` in any way. I cannot set `asset.attachment.path` manually.

Other questions on SO do not seem to address this specifically.
"[paperclip images not saving in the path i've set up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321473/paperclip-images-not-saving-in-the-path-ive-set-up)", "[Paperclip and Amazon S3 how to do paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476255/paperclip-and-amazon-s3-how-to-do-paths)", and so on involve setting up the model, which is already working fine.

Anyone have any insight to offer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, I *do* need to turn the S3 object into a `File`, as suggested by @oregontrail256. I used the [Fog](http://fog.io/) gem to do this.

```
s3 = Fog::Storage.new(
        :provider => 'AWS',
        :aws_access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
        :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
      )

directory = s3.directories.get(ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'])
fog_file = directory.files.get(path)

file = File.open("temp", "wb")
file.write(fog_file.body)
asset.attachment = file
asset.save
file.close
```

Answer (score 1):

Paperclip attachments have a copy_to_local_file() method that allows you to make a local copy of the attachment. So what about:

```
file_name = "temp_file"
asset1.attachment.copy_to_local_file(:style, file_name)
file = File.open(file_name)
asset2.attachment = file
file.close
asset2.save!
```

Even if you destroy asset1, you now have a copy of the attachment saved by asset2 separately. You probably want to do this in a background job if you're doing many of them.

Credit to this answer too: [How to set a file upload programmatically using Paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397461/how-to-set-file-programmatically-using-paperclip)

Comment: This probably works if the file in S3 is already attached to a different `Asset`, but in that case, I could just do `asset2.attachment = asset1.attachment`. We still have the same problem: given the bucket, path, and credentials, how to we create a Paperclip::Attachment?